# Regular expression match everything after newline

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to match a commit hash and the files associated with that hash. See the sample file below:

```
:6585d0f0ba88767ac3b590f719596d864d73e9c1:

harmonicbalance/src/harmonicbalance/HarmonicBalanceFlowModel.cpp
harmonicbalance/src/harmonicbalance/HbFlutterModel.cpp
:8302994b565553c83a048b8905ae597349d99627:

emp/src/emp/PhasePairSingleParticleReynoldsNumber.h
emp/src/emp/TomiyamaDragCoefficientMethod.cpp
:9da194f17ec08bb20ad1be8df68b78ca137ab18a:

combustion/src/combustion/ReactingSpeciesTransportBasedModel.cpp
combustion/src/complexchemistry/TurbulentFlameClosure.cpp
:6a59f0be1e347a65e525e58742bb304639ea9bc4:

meshing/src/meshing/SurfaceMeshManipulation.cpp
physics/src/discretization/FvIndirectRegionInterfaceManager.cpp
physics/src/discretization/FvIndirectRegionInterfaceManager.h
physics/src/discretization/FvRepresentation.cpp
physics/src/discretization/FvRepresentation.h
:64b7f6d36b11b6cd94c20cad53463b7deef8c85a:

resourceclient/src/resourceclient/ResourcePool.cpp
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/ResourcePool.h
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/RestClient.cpp
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/RestClient.h
resourceclient/src/resourceclient/test/ResourcePoolTest.cpp
```

Here's the regular expression that I came up with:

```
^:([A-Za-z0-9]+):[\n]+([A-Za-z]+\/.*[.a-z])$
```

This expression captures the commit hash and the first file.

How can I capture all files and all commits?

Comment: Where are you going to use this regex? What regex engine?

Comment: In Pentaho Data Integration ETL tool.

Comment: This step uses the java.util.regex package.

Comment: Try [`^:(\w+):\s+((?:\s*(?!:)[^\s]+)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oIoDvM/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this Java compliant regex using `\G`:

```
(?:^:([A-Za-z0-9]+):|(?!^)\G)\n+([A-Za-z/.-]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3IBkPz/1)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Comment: Thank you! It works in the the RegEx testing websites online but not in Pentaho. Probably I need to get in touch with the support. RegEx is great. I will accept your answer. :)